# PHP: Jump out of parent switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

I´d like to jump out of a parent switch-statement. Example:

```
switch(xyz){
 case "xyz":
   switch(xyz){
    case "hello":
      // JUMP OUT OF THIS TWO SWITCH-STATEMENTS
      break;
   }
   break;
}
```

Is there a simple way to realize this?

Comment: The fact that you have a `break` immediately after your inner switch means that as soon as that switch is done, control will exit the outer switch as well.

Comment: You need `break 2` http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: Nesting switches... yeesh. What do you mean by "jump out"? If you break where that comment is, it'll return out to the parent case, which will also break, exiting the switch. Is that what you want?

Comment: A solution was already found: break 2. Thank you!
@jonhopkins but if there is code after the second switch statement it will executed..

Comment: Yes, it would. I actually thought about that after posting my comment. In the case of languages that don't have the `break 2` feature, I would just use a boolean to check. Something along the lines of `switch (xyz) { case "xyz": $breakSwitch = false; switch (xyz) { case "hello": $breakSwitch = true; break; } if ($breakSwitch) { break; } }` It's not pretty, and not as efficient as `break 2`, but it works when it's necessary.

Comment: That is the alternative I also thought about. But I think break 2 is a pretty solution

Answer (score 2):

if you want to break out of the 2 switch statement you can use the optional argument to break

```
switch(xyz){
 case "xyz":
   switch(xyz){
    case "hello":
      // JUMP OUT OF THIS TWO SWITCH-STATEMENTS
      break 2;
   }
   break;
}
```

check the second example in http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the [break 2;](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

`break` is nothing else than `break 1` - so in your case quitting the second switch.

`break 2` will quit the second switch AND the first switch.

```
switch(xyz){
 case "xyz":
   switch(xyz){
    case "hello":
      // JUMP OUT OF THIS TWO SWITCH-STATEMENTS
      break 2;
   }
   break;
}
```